# Is there a link between confirmation biases and a tendency to subscribe to religions?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, bias, religion

I've just read Rolf Dobelli's **The Art of Thinking Clearly**, as well as Mark Manson's **Everything is F*cked**, which I stumbled upon the concept of cognitive biases.

In the books they mentioned how religions are required to maintain hope and seemingly control over humanity, and their strategies of exclusion (ie us vs them). Regarding this, it seems to have an overlap with confirmation bias.

As such, is there a deeper relationship between the two?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but can you describe a bit more what exactly do you mean by overlapping with confirmation bias? An example, maybe?

Comment: @Jan it may be poor word choice but what I am trying to suggest is how they have influences over each other in that sense? For instance we see religions protecting their own gods or deities to bond devotees together and etc, which is confirmation bias in a way.

Comment: From which perspective are you looking to this: How religions were created or how they influence people? So, who is about to be biased - the religion creator or the religion participant? From the question in your title, I guess the latter?

Comment: @Jan yep i meant the latter. I would like to look more into influence in people, especially devotees or followers of religions.